# Surjective operator between Banach spaces takes closed unit ball to a closed set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Assume $X$ is a Banach spaces, $Y$ is a finite-dimensional normed space, and let $T: X \to Y$ be a (linear, continuous) onto operator. The open mapping theorem asserts that $T$ is open. However, it need not be closed (the canonical projection $\pi_1: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, \ \pi_1(x,y)=x$ is a counterexample).

My question is: can we infer that $T$ takes bounded closed subsets to (bounded) closed subsets in $Y$? It is is certainly true for *reflexive* Banach spaces, by a weak compactness argument. I would like this to be true for any Banach space $X$.

Comment: The statement for closed balls is not equivalent to the statement for arbitrary closed bounded sets.  For instance, if $\ker(T)$ is infinite-dimensional, you can find a sequence of unit vectors in $X$ with no accumulation point that $T$ maps to a sequence of nonzero vectors that approach $0$ (take a sequence of unit vectors in $\ker(T)$ with no accumulation point and perturb them a bit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true.  For instance, consider the functional $T:\ell^1\to\mathbb{R}$ corresponding to a unit vector in $\ell^\infty$ that does not attain its sup norm (for instance, the sequence $(0,1/2,2/3,3/4,\dots)$).  Then the image of the closed unit ball under $T$ will be the interval $(-1,1)$ which is not closed.

Comment: Wonderful counterexample, thank you very much!

Comment: It seems that the functional $T:C_{\mathbb{R}} [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ $$Tf=\int\limits_0^{1/2}f(x)\,dx -\int\limits_{1/2}^1f(x)\,dx $$ provides another example based on a similar idea.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc this is also very interesting, thanks a lot!